# Flask session expiration and CSRF

Tags: python, flask, session-cookies, csrf

I would like to have a Flask session where the session cookie expires after 2 weeks regardless of activity.

I can get this to work without CSRF by setting:

```
SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST=False
```

but this doesn't work when I enable CSRF.

With CSRF, the CSRF token is updated in the session for each request which causes the session expiration to be reset.

It seems that the only way to make the session expire after 2 weeks is to do it yourself (e.g., store the login date in the session or user database and deleting the session when the login date is more than 2 weeks old).

This seems like a common requirement so just curious if I am missing something?

Comment: If you don't want to store it in db, why not try to use JWT as session token?

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to store date somewhere and then every day check if it has been >= 2 weeks since the stored date

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).